# Retrieving the time stamp of the received message

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, orchestration, biztalk-orchestrations

I could not figure how to retrieve the time stamp of the received messages. Based on the time the messages received I have to send emails to two different send ports. I understand how can I dynamically send the messages but dont know, how can I decide based on the time it arrives.

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What adapter are you using? Depending on the adapter, a different property might be set when the file/msg was received.

Comment: Using the file adapter in the receive side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the File Adapter, you can read out the `FileCreationTime` Property of the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties` NameSpace. This Property holds the DateTime when the file was **created** in the file location monitored by the adapter.

When you want the DateTime of the message when it was **received** in BizTalk, you should use the `AdapterReceiveCompleteTime` of the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/messagetracking-properties` NameSpace.

[image]

Comment: how can I compare the AdapterReceiveCompleteTime with the time say 7.00 am. Should it be in the send port or through the orchestration

Comment: You can read this property in a Pipeline or Orchestration. You should be able to use it like: msg_MyMessage(MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime)

Comment: In the decide shape of orchestration under Rule I used this RM(MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime) == 07:00:00; I am getting error.

Comment: You should first parse your string to DateTime:
RM(MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime) ==  System.DateTime.Parse("07:00:00")

Comment: Oh Thank you so much. That was a great mistake. I didnt realize.

Comment: Is it possible to use <= in the Rule to compare the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

Using the FILE adapter, you have a FileCreationTime property, set by the FILE adapter. This is not the timestamp of receiving, but might be sufficient for your cause.

[image]

If you need to have the EXACT timestamp when you received the file, you would need to create a custom pipeline component that either:

- includes it in the message somewhere
- or writes/promotes a property in the context of the message using DateTime.Now for example.

You can then use it in a mapping or content based routing somewhere.

I think these are your options.

Comment: Pieter Vandenheede how can I compare the FileCreationTime with the time say 7.00 am. Should it be in the send port or through the orchestration